# User Permissions error for reading from view in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres and have a new read-only user that has read permissions on all tables in a base schema. I was trying to `SELECT` some data from a particular view from base schema and was able to see the values from the view. To test the data count I had to make some changes in the view definition and in Postgres there isnt a way to alter the View so I had to `drop` and `recreate` the view with new definition using a older user with higher privilege. Now I run the same `SELECT` query on the View and am getting a permissions error.

```
 ERROR:  permission denied for view 
SQL state: 42501
```

I tried `Grant SELECT on ALL TABLES on Schema base to user` again and was able to see the values from the view. What I dont get is that I havent changed any syntax since the first `GRANT`, why am I having to run the `GRANT SELECT` statement again for the new user to be able to access the view ? shouldnt the user already be able to access all the tables and views by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` to change a view definition if you don't change its columns.

In PostgreSQL, permissions are stored on the object. If you drop an object, all its permissions are gone. If you later create an object with the same name, that is still a different object and will have the default permissions.

You can use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to grant permissions for objects that are created in the future.